# Heading overlaps the list

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hello my wonderful peeps.

The heading "whatever" overlaps on my list.

I want the list to appear after the heading.

```
<div style="width:1024px;height=auto;position:absoulte;min-height:768px;">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>Whatever</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="list" id="listID" >
        <div style="height:15px;">Nope</div>
        <div style="height:15px;">Yes</div>
        <div style="height:15px;">Maybe</div>
        <div style="height:15px;">Definetely</div>
    </div>
    <button>Print</button>
    <button style="posititon:relative;top:0px;">add</button>
</div>
```

and this is the css

```
.heading
{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
}

.list
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:10px;
    top:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zd5n3L5z/

Help me out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change top to margin top for the heading

```
.heading
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.list
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:10px;
    top:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: top will only move the element but doesn't affect the layout where as margin-top does both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont want to affect the possition in relation to other elements, you don't need to use the relative attribut. So your 'CSS' should look like:

```
.heading
{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.list
{
   min-height:10px;
   margin-left:20px;
}
```

This will keep your css clean!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline` in class `.list`:

**css**

```
.heading
{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
}

.list
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:10px;
    top:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    display: inline;/*Add display inline*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zd5n3L5z/7/)

> **inline** This value causes an element to generate one or more inline
>   boxes.

Also you have a syntax error in your main `div` container. Is `position:absolute` no `absoulte`.

Answer (score 0):

You set the .heading top:50px. What happens here is that this value (50px) is not relative to the .list but to the div it sits in. Simply change the value like this:

```
.heading
{
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use position top for ".heading" class

```
.heading
{
    position:relative;

}

.list
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:10px;

    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
button{clear:both;}
```